# Use referral parameter to navigate in the main dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework

Any clear help would really be appreciated.

So I made a bot, in NodeJS, then my bot needs to handle bot facebook and web bot conversations. Messenger conversations can be open through m.me link which has a referral parameter. The web bot is the same as usual converstations, user message and based on my LUIS result, navigates to a specific dialog.

The problem was when I capture the referral paramter in the onMessage ActivityHandler dialog, the bot captures it but then says error.

`const dummy = context.activity.channelData.referral.ref;`

I used that segment of code to print out the referral parameter and it thus work, however there's an error after even declaring it. My question, is how to I transfer the referral dialog to my MainDialog

THIS IS MY Index.js

`const applicationDialog = new ApplicationDialog(APPLICATION_DIALOG);
const dialog = new MainDialog(luisRecognizer, applicationDialog);
const bot = new DialogAndWelcomeBot(conversationState, userState, dialog);`

- DialogandWelcomeBot dialog extends **Dialog which contains the onMessage activity**, and captures the referral parameter.
  -applicationDialog is the main dialog which needs to process the referral parameter.

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ANY HELP AND CLARIFICATION MY MASTERS! <3

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the error you receive?

Comment: thank you for your active response Sir @StevenKanberg, I figure out the problem and how to solve it. The problem was channelData.referral doesn't exist because after a new message in messenger, which in my case a quick_reply, contains no new referral anymore. So to solve this, I used if-statement to check whether .referral doesn't exist.